# Object of type System.Linq.EnumerableQuery cannot be converted to type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerab

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm running into a problem retrieving XML datatype with OData Query on the Web API, but in JSON format there is no problem at all.

**Error saying this :**

> ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Wrapper.SelectSome`1[OData_WebAPI.WeatherForecast]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[OData_WebAPI.WeatherForecast]'.

I'm just testing it on the sample Controller **`WeatherForecastController.cs`** file when you create a new Web API project.

```
    [HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast/{format}"), FormatFilter]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

Retrieving XML datatype without OData Query works fine, but I want it to work with OData Query, How to do that? hoping anyone could help me.

**This works :**

```
https://localhost:7110/WeatherForecast/GetWeatherForecast/xml
```

**But not this**

```
https://localhost:7110/WeatherForecast/GetWeatherForecast/xml?$select=Summary
```

Comment: Could you please have a look on the [`example here`](https://github.com/kironiitdu/-kironiitdu-Odata8RoutingPrefix/blob/main/Controllers/v1/CustomersController.cs). Let us know if that fit within your expectations. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron can you help me with this : [InvalidDataContractException: Type cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72265860/invaliddatacontractexception-type-cannot-be-serialized-consider-marking-it-wit)

Comment: I have checked your link unfortunately it has been deleted I guess.